# Calling multiple REST API’s using Splunk

Tags: splunk

Is it possible to call multiple api’s using Splunk to get data? To be more specific I’m trying to call two api’s, one for login to get token and other call will use the token from previous call to get data. If so can you please brief how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You will need to develop your own script to call the REST endpoints. The output of your script would be read by Splunk

Alternatively, you can investigate this existing app, https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1546/#/details